# How to get gradient (dL/dw) during training in Pytorch?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch

```
class ConvNet(torch.nn.Module):
 def __init__(self):

   super(ConvNet, self).__init__()
   self.conv1 = torch.nn.Conv2d(1, 6, 5)
   self.pool = torch.nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
   self.conv2 = torch.nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)
   self.fc1 = torch.nn.Linear(16 * 4 * 4, 62)

 def forward(self, x):
   x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
   x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
   x = x.view(-1, 16 * 4 * 4)
   x = self.fc1(x)
   return x
```

---

```
for x, y in loader:
  x, y = x.to(device), y.to(device)
  optimizer.zero_grad()
  loss = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(model(x), y)
  loss.backward()

  print(Convnet().conv1.weight.grad)

  optimizer.step()
```

I tried `Convnet().conv1.weight.grad`, but it gives `None` output. What are the other options to print gradient in Pytorch?

Comment: You are investigating a new instance of `ConvNet` instead of `model`.

Comment: Yes it should be model.conv1.weight.grad

Answer (score 4):

Okay, a few things to note here:

1. I'm assuming you have already instantiated/initialized your `ConvNet` class with an object called `model`. (`model = ConvNet()`)
2. The way you're accessing the model's weight gradients is correct, however, you're using the *wrong object* to access these weights. Specifically, you're supposed to use the **instantiated** running model to access these gradients, which is the `model` object you instantiated. When you use `ConvNet().conv1.weight.grad`, you're creating a **new instance** of the class `ConvNet()` on **every call**, and none of these instances were used to process your data `x`, hence they all give `None` for gradients.
3. Based on the above points, the correct way to access the gradients is to use your instaniated model which you've used to process your data, which is:
   `model.conv1.weight.grad`
4. Side note; you might want to use torch's functional API to find the loss as it's more readable: `loss = F.cross_entropy(model(x), y)`